# How can I select and output the first and last row of a worksheet or a filtered list?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I am new to VBA and I have no clue where to start with this.

I have two columns of data:

```
Team Member Time
A             1
A             2
A             3
A             4
```

I am only interested in the first and last row of this spreadsheet, and my anticipated output is this:

```
Team Member Time
A             1
A             4
```

The total number of rows in my spreadsheet keep changing, so there is no fixed last row.

Are there simple excel functions that can help me with this which I can record using a macro or should I create a function using VBA for this?

Here is the macro that just selects the 2nd and 3rd row to delete it:

```
Sub Del()
Rows("3:4").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

But this obviously doesn't work when the number of rows vary.

Comment: There are some details missing here. Are there more than team member A in the list? Do you want the first and last row regardless of the team member? What have you attempted so far?

Comment: @CharlieRB There is only one team member in the list. I need the first and last rows of that one team member only. Till now I was manually deleting all the rows in between. Next, I recorded a macro which deletes the middle rows only when the total number of rows is a 100. However, now since the number of rows vary I cannot use this macro any more.

Comment: Since you have already done the work, it may have been a better question to ask how to make your macro do what you want. Why not post it here so we can see if we can help you adjust it to work the way you want; delete all rows except the first and last. That seems better than starting from scratch.

Comment: @CharlieRB : It wasn't anything significant, which is why I hadn't provided it. I have included it in the question now.

Comment: Are there any blank rows within the data?  It appears that the first row is always in a known location, so that's trivial to get (just reference it).  If there are no blank rows, count entries and offset for the first row to get the last row.  This just requires a function, no VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you are attempting to use VBA to simplify your tasks is great! Your macro may have been simple, but it was a good start.

Below is a macro you can paste into `ThisWorkbook` in the VBA explorer. When run, it will find the last row, select the range in between the first and last row (assuming A1 is always the first), then delete the range leaving you with the first and last row.

```
Sub Del()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim DataRange As Range

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow = LastRow - 1
Set DataRange = Range("A2:B" & LastRow)

DataRange.Delete

End Sub
```

**Note: This macro deletes data! Use at your own risk.**

Comment: Worked like a charm! I should try understanding the code though. I just changed `"A2:B"` to `"A3:B"` so that the output includes the column headers and the first and the last rows below it.

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(ROW()=2,"alpha",IF(B3="","omega",""))
```

and copy down.  Then *Autofilter* column **C** to display *alpha* and *omega*.

[image]